# Почему body вылазит за footer при отдалении страницы?

Tags: html, css

Почему body вылазит за footer при отдалении страницы? Что нужно изменить в css? Временная ссылка на сайт: http://skidon-legko.ru

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а почему он не должен _вылазить_?

Comment: Можно конкретный ответ? Что нужно изменить в css чтобы не вылазило?

Comment: Можно конкретный вопрос? как определить что изменить, если неизвестно какой css сейчас?

Comment: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5263/186999)

Comment: http://rgho.st/87xWmRDJW Вот собственно проблемный index и css файл

Comment: прочитай ответ по ссылке из моего комментария выше